# Jquery datepicker max date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery UI datepicker and I want to set the max date to be 31 march of the current financial year( from 01 april to 31st march of every year). I do not want the user to select the max date which exceeds the current financial year. I am capturing the user input year and based on that I want to set the max date to be the 31st March of the entered financial year.

For example, if I select today (Nov 03 2014) then my max date should be Mar 31 2015. How to achive that.

I have tried this code but it gives the current year only and I get 2014.

```
var Now = new Date();               
var maxDate = Date.parse("31/03/"+Now.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to limit it in the datepicker itself or can they pick a future date and then the max date gets calculated? (i.e. Like if they enter in a date in 2015 you want 2016 to be the max date?)

Comment: yes, that is what I want, if they enter a date in 2015, but that should be (any date after 01 April 2015) then my max date should be 31st March 2016. If user enter 30 March 2015, then Max date should be 31 March 2015, because it is still under the current financial year (i.e. 01 April 2014 to 31 March 2015)

Comment: basically there are two fields, one is where I am capturing the year and based on that field I am seting the max date on the other field where I have the UI date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method you are trying to do now, if you have all the right logic to check the dates, then you just need to add one year to your `Now` variable (or the date variable passed in from the datepicker).

To do this you can either:

```
var Now = new Date();               
Now.setFullYear( Now.getFullYear() + 1);
```

OR - You can do it how you are doing it and:

```
var maxDate = Date.parse( "31/03/"+ (Now.getFullYear() + 1 ) );
```

Now.getFullYear() returns an integer so you can do addition on it.

**EDIT**

```
var nextFinanicalYearMonth = 4;
if(datePicked.getMonth() >= nextFinancialYearMonth)
{
   var maxDate = datePicked.parse("31/03/" + (datePicked.getFullYear() + 1) );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with this solution, if I select 01 Jan 2014, then it will set the max date to be 31/03/2015...which I don't want because 01 Jan 2014 is in the financial year between 01 April 2014 to 31 March 2015, so my max date should be 31 March 2015.

Comment: Year calculation is based on  (01 April to 31st March of given year) (financial year)

Comment: That's why I have my disclaimer at the beginning that if you have the right logic to check which date they set. Sounds like you just need to implement some simple logic that says if they selected after March 31, then you need to increment the year that they picked. I'll try to update my answer to better explain